# display mysql code output in jsp page

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I want to calculate total time in the give days. values are inserted from the retrieve.jsp page and it shows the result on cal.jsp page. I know that it is a bad idea to put SQL code or any database related code in JSP. But I want to try this way please help.

retrieve.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import="com.eis.bean.Provider"%>
<%@page import="com.eis.bean.ConnectionProvider"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="com.eis.servlet.RetrieveServlet"%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Enter Employee ID and the dates</h4>
    <form name="retrieve form" action="cal.jsp" method="POST">
        <table border="0">

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Employee ID</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Emp_id" required="required"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>From Date:</td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="From" value="yyyy/MM/dd" required="required"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>To Date:</td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="To" value="yyyy/MM/dd" required="required"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="clear" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cal.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="com.eis.bean.Provider"%>
<%@page import="com.eis.bean.ConnectionProvider"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="com.eis.servlet.RetrieveServlet"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:include page="retrieve.jsp"/>
<%
String empid = request.getParameter("Emp_id");
String from = request.getParameter("From");
String to = request.getParameter("To");
Connection conn= null;
PreparedStatement ps1= null; 
ResultSet rs1= null; 

     conn = ConnectionProvider.getConn(); 

    ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`total`))) AS Total FROM timsheetdb.logintable WHERE Emp_id=? AND LoginDate BETWEEN ? AND ?;");

    ps1.setString(1, empid); 
    ps1.setString(2, from);
    ps1.setString(3, to);

    rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
      String Total=null;
        while (rs1.next())  
        {
           Total = rs1.getString("Total");
           out.println("Total is : " + Total + "<br>");
        }

 %>
```

error which I got:

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /cal.jsp at line 28

25:           String Total=null;
26:             while (rs1.next())  
27:             {
28:                Total = rs1.getString("Total");
29:                out.println("Total is : " + Total + "<br>");
30:             }
31:              


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '27' for java.sql.Time type in value '27:00:00.
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
org.apache.jsp.cal_jsp._jspService(cal_jsp.java:143)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '27' for java.sql.Time type in value '27:00:00.
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
com.mysql.jdbc.TimeUtil.fastTimeCreate(TimeUtil.java:286)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.fastTimeCreate(ResultSetImpl.java:973)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimeFromString(ResultSetImpl.java:5558)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5319)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5173)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5212)
org.apache.jsp.cal_jsp._jspService(cal_jsp.java:125)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I think its causing this error beacause of java.sql.SQLException: Illegal hour value '27' for java.sql.Time type in value '27:00:00 .
I my database i set the Total column to Timestamp type.

I have tried in sql its working fine below is the image
[image]

Comment: your query is not correct.First try to get query right by invoking directly on database.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta thanks for the quick reply I tried in the database its working i have added the image please check

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta, I really appreciate you being on this forum prince. I hope you remember me. Your blog is very nice too. I checked it. Add a contact me page there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try please convert timestamp to string with cast function. For example;

```
SELECT CAST((SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`total`))) ) AS char) AS Total FROM timeornek.logintable  WHERE user=50 AND total BETWEEN '2015-10-13 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-25 00:00:00'
```