# MySQL query error "Illegal hour value" causing loop and write issues in Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, mariadb, try-catch

I'm not well-versed in either language, so please bear with me on this. I'm trying to pull a full table with 100 rows from a remote MySQL database into a Google Sheet. I've managed to sort all the issues I've been having with this, but finally feel stuck. It seems the "illegal hour value" error I get from the SQL query during the loop is the main problem.

One of the columns in the MySQL database is "duration", and unfortunately, it can contain durations longer than 23:59:59. I only have access to call the procedure and cannot make any changes to the table. I get the

> "illegal hour value"

error when a *row hits a duration longer than 24 hours (e.g., 70:00:00)*. I tried to simplify things by using a try-catch to skip the error and continue writing on the Google Sheet, but then I get the

> "number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range.The data has X but the range has Y"

error in the final sheet.getRange() line.

I'm also unable to figure out how to pass multiple statements when executing the MySQL query. I tried to understand addBatch and a couple of other things, but it becomes too complicated for me. Maybe there's a simpler solution with the query, or maybe that's the only solution, because it just might work if I can also add a CONCAT query after the CALL query to convert the "duration" column to string before the data goes into the loop.

***The code below has been updated to include the solution:***

```
function getData3(query, sheetName) {
  
  //MySQL (MariaDB) connection and statements.
  var user = '';
  var userPwd = '';
  var url = 'jdbc:mysql://remote.server.example.com/database_name';
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, user, userPwd);
  var stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
  stmt2.setMaxRows(100);
  var rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery('CALL spdAdminGetPIREPS(api_key)');
  //Logger.log(rs2)

  //Function to convert raw binary data to string to be used for durations >23:59:59.
  function byteArrToString(byteArr){
    return Utilities.newBlob(byteArr).getDataAsString();
  }

  //Setting up spreadsheet, results array, and cell range.
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("sheet_name");
  var results = [];
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;

  //Loop to get column names.
  cols = rs2.getMetaData();
  colNames = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= cols.getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
    //Logger.log(cols.getColumnName(i));
    colNames.push(cols.getColumnName(i));
  }
  results.push(colNames);

  //Loop to get row data, catch type errors due to duration >23:59:59 and fix it.
  var rowCount = 1;
  while(rs2.next()) {
    curRow = rs2.getMetaData();
    rowData = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= curRow.getColumnCount(); i++) {
      try {
      rowData.push(rs2.getString(i));
      } catch (e){
      var bytes = rs2.getBytes(i);
      rowData.push(byteArrToString(bytes)); //Pushes converted raw binary data as string using function defined above.
      //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rs2.getBytes(i))); //To see the raw binary data returned by getBytes() for durations >23:59:59 that throw an error.
        continue;
      }
    }
    results.push(rowData);
    rowCount++;
  }

  //Write data to sheet.
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, cols.getColumnCount()).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, cols.getColumnCount()).setValues(results);

  //Close result set, conn, and statement.
  //Logger.log(results);
  rs2.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

I know the two separate statements and all look ridiculous, but it seems they work, because I don't get the "no database" error with the query anymore. The simpler, single-line JDBC connector did not work for me, hence the current format for connecting to the MySQL server (Mariadb).

If there are no durations in the table longer than 24 hours, the code works and successfully writes the entire table into the Google Sheet.

**To sum:**

If I don't use try-catch, the loop stops with the error. If I use try-catch and continue, I get the number of columns mismatch error.

The end goal is to call the procedure and write the entire table onto a Google Sheet. Skipping problematic cells I can probably work with, but I'd definitely love to grab all of the data. I might be missing something trivial here, but any direction or help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498998/dynamic-sql-returns-syntax-error-on-google-apps-script-using-jdbc-and-mysql) question answered here, but cannot figure out how to utilize it in my case. I think that if I can pass multiple queries, I should be able to send a `CONCAT` query following the `CALL` query to convert the "duration" column from `Datetime` (I believe) to `string`.

**UPDATE 2:**
@TheMaster's solution for `try-catch` helped with skipping the problematic cell and continue writing the rest. I'd love to find a way to convert all durations (the entire column or the ones `>23:59:59`) to `string` to capture *all* the data.

**UPDATE 3:**
Based on @TheMaster's suggestions, using `getInt()` instead of `getString()` partially works by returning the hour but not the minutes (e.g., returns `34` if duration is `34:22:00`). Need a way to *convert* when `getString()` is used.

**UPDATE 4 (edited):**
Using `getBytes()`, the values returned are:
`[51,52,58,52,56,58,48,48]` for `34:48:00`
`[51,55,58,48,48,58,48,48]` for `37:00:00`
`[56,55,58,48,48,58,48,48]` for `87:00:00`
`[49,53,49,58,51,53,58,48,48]` for `151:35:00`
Which means:
`[48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58]` corresponds to `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,:]`. How can I incorporate this conversion?

Using `getLong()`, the values returned are:
`34` for `34:48:00`, converted to duration -> `816:00`
`37` for `37:00:00`, converted to duration -> `888:00`
`87` for `87:00:00`, converted to duration -> `2088:00`

**UPDATE FINAL:**
@TheMaster's modified answer solved the problem by getting raw binary data and converting to string for durations `>23:59:59`. Code above has been updated to reflect all modifications; it works as written above.

Comment: any reasons why you don't want to use `text` for this column?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ I thought about converting the type of that column from the result I get with the query, but I couldn't figure out how. Is that what you mean or is there another way?

Comment: I've also tried adding a `getMaxColumns()` to avoid the number of columns error. I added it before the two `sheet.getRange()` lines at the bottom of my code. Not sure how to best add it anywhere and whether or not that'll solve the problem. Working on it.

Comment: Could you add the `CREATE PROCEDURE` you made to create `spdAdminGetPIREPS`?

Comment: @TheMaster, unfortunately, I can only see the procedures when connected to the database, and not the tables they query. I'm trying to figure out if I can find out the `CREATE PROCEDURE` used.

Comment: `getBytes()` returns a array of numbers. Could you update the code to show how you're logging the code? Could you try `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rs2.getBytes(i)))`?

Comment: @TheMaster - This is genius! I guess I wasn't paying attention to the documentation for what `getBytes()` returns. I've come to expect errors when an array could not be written because cell are not empty, but this is different, of course. It looks like bytes correspond to each unit of a duration type (e.g., 49->1, 51->3, 58->":"). How could I incorporate this conversion?

Comment: Edited my answer. Consider accepting it, if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip failed `getString()`, it should be easy:

```js
try {
      rowData.push(rs2.getString(i));
      } catch (e){
      rowData.push("");//Keeps array straight
        continue;
      }
```

If you want to convert the time column to string, you need to use [`CAST(time AS char)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) or [`CONCAT('',time)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232078/) on the `CREATE_PROCEDURE` query used to create `spdAdminGetPIREPS`

Alternatively, You can get the raw binary data using [`resultSet.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes(int)) and change it back to `string` through `blob` using [`Utilities`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(Byte)):

```
function byteArrToString(byteArr){
 return Utilities.newBlob(byteArr).getDataAsString();
}
```

Use it as

```
var bytes = rs2.getBytes();
rowData.push(byteArrToString(bytes));
```

If you could directly get blob, it will be easier to get [`appsScriptBlob`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-blob.html#getAppsScriptBlob())

```
var jdbcBlob = rs2.getBlob();
var blob = jdbcBlob.getAppsScriptBlob();
rowData.push(blob.getDataAsString());
jdbcBlob.free();
```

Comment: Thank you, @TheMaster! The addition of `rowData.push("");` skips the problematic cell and continues writing the rest. I'd, of course, prefer to convert the problematic cell/column to string, but I don't have edit access on the `CREATE_PROCEDURE` -- just the access to `CALL` the stored procedure. Anyway I can add the `CONCAT` after `CALL` in GAS?

Comment: So far, I tried separating queries on the same line with a "\" , ";", and "," but all of that comes back with syntax errors, even though I can use `;` when directly connected to the database and sending simple queries. I also tried adding `stmt2.executeUpdate('CONCAT("",time');` but still get a syntax error. I'm probably doing that wrong, but cannot figure out the correct way in GAS.

Comment: @Bears You need to know the CREATE_PROCEDURE syntax and be able to modify it. If not, could you directly use `SELECT bla,bla,time FROM..` instead of CALLing a stored procedure? As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637288), I don't think it's possible to get a table from CALL and hence I don't think it's possible to use CAST/CONCAT. Disclaimer: Not a sql expert.

Comment: It seems that even if they tell me what `CREATE_PROCEDURE` they used, I will not have access to make any modifications. I can only `CALL` and use that result set. I don't even have the table_name. My only option seems to be able to store that result set in an array and make modifications before writing onto the sheet, but that means I can't use the loop with `getString()` to iterate through the CALL result set as that throws an error. Maybe another loop method to iterate through rows without `getString()`?

Comment: I also cannot do a direct `SELECT` query, because I don't have access to the table in the database, just the procedure that pulls from that table.

Comment: @Bears Try any of the other `get*` methods listed in the documentation like `getObject()`. If that doesn't work, I can't help you.

Comment: I tried all the `get*` methods listed. `getInt()` does work, but only grabs the hour (e.g., returns 35 for 35:23:00) -- so I lose the minutes. `getLong()` does the same. Other `get*` methods don't work. I'm trying to find a method to _convert_ when `getString()` is used, but may not be possible, at all.

Comment: @Bears What about `getFloat()` or `getBytes()`?

Comment: Tried all `get*` methods. `getFloat()` doesn't work, throws the same `type` error. `getBytes()` returns a nonsensical number that I could not turn into duration. `getInt()` and `getLong()` return the hour of duration. This is driving me crazy. There's gotta be a way to get that cell value as a string or another format that would make sense.

Comment: @Bears  *getBytes() returns a nonsensical number that I could not turn into duration* That's great. Could you edit your question to show what you get and what's the expected duration for that *nonsensical* number?

Comment: My apologies; seemingly nonsensical returned values _could_ make sense, of course. I updated the question above.

Comment: Your edited answer solved it! Thank you for not giving up on me. :) Updating my code above to reflect changes and solution. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Could not get `getBlob()` to work, but I might be doing it wrong. I used the four lines you wrote, added `i` for `Column Index`, and get a `Service error: JdbcBlob` for line `rowData.push(blob.getDataAsString());` -- what did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

You currently use MySQL connector, and even if [TIME](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/time/) value can be from '-838:59:59.999999' to '838:59:59.999999', MySQL driver throws an exception when getting a value of a TIME type not in the 0-24 hour range. 
This can make sense when using Resultset.getTime(i) when not really but doesn't when using Resultset.getString(i).

This can be disabled using `noDatetimeStringSync=true`, so changing URL to `jdbc:mysql://remote.server.example.com?noDatetimeStringSync=true`

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of MariaDB java driver, but I would recommend to use MariaDB driver with MariaDB server (and MySQL one with MySQL server). You would have avoid this issue :)

btw, you can directly set database in URL `jdbc:mysql://remote.server.example.com/database?noDatetimeStringSync=true` avoiding a query.

Comment: Thank you, Diego. I added the database to the URL, and that works -- must have done something wrong before when it did not work.However, when I just now added the `?noDatetimeStringSync=true` at the end, I got an error saying "The following connection properties are unsupported: noDatetimeStringSync." I changed the URL as you suggested. I also looked [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/) to figure out how to use the MariaDB connector (jdbc:mariadb://) but then I'm getting "unsupported JDBC protocol" when trying to use `Jdbc.getConnection(url)`. What am I missing?

Comment: This is the URL I tried: `jdbc:mariadb://remote.server.example.com/database?user=xxx&password=xxx&noDatetimeStringSync=true`

Comment: Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221861/12140720). It says mariadb is not supported in GAS and that I'd need to write my own REST API layer.

Comment: hmm, google apps has a whitelist of supported options, and noDatetimeStringSync isn't permitted. I would recommend to create an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025

Comment: Yeah, will create an issue. I was unable to pass other parameters, either. I'll check the whitelist and create an issue. Thanks, Diego!